# EcomDev PHPUnit Fixtures Magento

Tags: magento-enterprise, ecomdev-phpunit, phpunit

I am creating a fixtures yaml file to create a sample product for my unit tests - using the EcomDev phpunit plugin for Magento.

The issue is that I need to set store specific values for price.  I have managed to get this working fine for website specific values like so:

```
eav:
  catalog_product:
    - entity_id: 1
      type_id: simple
      sku: book
      name: Book
      short_description: Book
      description: Book
      url_key: book
      price: 12.99
      tax_class_id: 2
      status: 1
      visibility:
      /websites:
        uk: # this is the website code
          price: 12.99
```

However when I try with stores instead of websites at the bottom, the store specific values are not being set:

```
/stores:
  artista_uk: # this store does exist in the database
    price: 16.99
```

The way I have tested this is by viewing the catalog_product_entity_decimal table and seeing if a price value appears next to the relevant store id.

The documentation can be found here: 
http://www.ecomdev.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/EcomDev_PHPUnit-0.2.0-Manual.pdf
Which does say you can interchange websites with stores

Any ideas would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that **artista_uk** is code of store not store_group? This should work

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can accomplish to do that because price in Magento is limited to global or website scope.

As far as I know, no different prices can be set on same product for different store views belonging to same website.

Kind regards

Comment: Additionally you have to set the config value to use the website scope, if you don't do this, the website price is ignored! See `\Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Price::setScope`

Comment: To Fabian's point, you can also set this inside the fixture:    `config:
default/catalog/price/scope: 1 # Set price scope to website`